# storing sensor readings through numpy to a data file ( python 2.7 )

Tags: python, numpy

Im fetching acceleration reading of 3 axis from sensor and trying to export it to a data file through numpy.

function 'lsm6ds33.get_accelerometer_g_forces()'  returns a list of floating point like [0.5455445 , 0.2565622 0.0545412]

Im getting n empty data file,
Can i use logging function to make it.

regards.

accelArray= lsm6ds33.get_accelerometer_g_forces() #temp variable to hold the array

and

DataOut = column_stack(accelArray) 
doesnot help.

```
from altimu10v5.lsm6ds33 import LSM6DS33
from time import sleep
import numpy as np

lsm6ds33 = LSM6DS33()
lsm6ds33.enable()

while True:


    DataOut = column_stack(lsm6ds33.get_accelerometer_g_forces())
    savetxt('output.dat', DataOut, fmt=( '%2.2f', '%2.2f', '%2.2f'))
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: You indented your code somewhere and you shouldn't have. That's what error is saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding the `savetxt` input to a 2D array worked for me. Try:

```py
x = [0.5455445, 0.2565622, 0.0545412]
np.savetxt('output.dat',np.reshape(x, (1,3)),  fmt='%2.2f %2.2f %2.2f')
```

or:

```py
x = [0.5455445, 0.2565622, 0.0545412]
np.savetxt('output.dat',np.expand_dims(x, axis=0),  fmt='%2.2f %2.2f %2.2f')
```

Comment: hei.
the question is answered , 
anyway now i have one set of reading only , i need the sensor reading to be done in more times / cycles.

how could this be achievable.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Example?

Comment: the function returns several arrays like
[0.2555 , 0.152455 , 0.545455]
[0.5454, 0.1455 , 0.5455]
[0.2555 , 0.152455 , 0.545455]

now im exporting first row only to the data file.
how to save the all entry's.

Comment: Please make another thread, showing example code that you have tried and the error that you get when running it.